# How to pass/extract text from span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pass value of span to callback on click ?

```
<span class="test" onClick="testFunction(this);">Test</span>

function testFunction(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

But I always get in alert

```
{}
```

How to pass/extract text from span ?
I need to have onClick inside tag, not to attach on another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the element to the function correctly.

It's when you use `JSON.stringify` that you don't get any result. The element only has members defined in its prototype, it doesn't have any members added to the object instance itself. The `stringify` function only includes members of the object instance, not from its prototype, so you get the same as if you called it on an empty object.

If you get some property from the element and show that, you see that you actually have a reference to it:

```
function testFunction(e) {
  alert(e.tagName); // shows "SPAN"
}
```

or:

```
function testFunction(e) {
  alert(e.innerHTML); // shows "Test"
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F3S4T/

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
<span class="test" onClick="testFunction(this);">Test</span>

function testFunction(elem) {
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the content inside the span tags (or any HTML tags) you can use the innerHTML property of the element. E.g,

```
function testFunction(e) {
    alert(e.innerHTML);
}
```